# Filtering video and adding metadata in one step failed

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I want to filter a video stream

```
-vf crop=300:ih,mpdecimate
```

and add metadata for it to the output video:

```
-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90
```

This command filter it, but the **metadata are NOT added**:

```
ffmpeg -to 6 -i input.3gp -vf crop=300:ih,mpdecimate \
       -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 \
        output.mp4
```

But I do the same in **2 steps**  (using a temporary output as input),
the result is OK, the **metadata ARE added**:

```
ffmpeg -to 6 -i input.3gp -vf crop=300:ih,mpdecimate \
       temp.mp4

ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -c copy \
       -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 \
        output.mp4
```

My question is:

> Is it impossible to filter a video **and** add some metadata in one step?

---

*Part of FFprobe output:*

For the successful **2-steps** method:

> ```
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : Core Media Video
>       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
>     Side data:
>       displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
> ```

For the **1-step** method, the last 2 rows are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rotate tag is ignored for encoded video streams.

Should be patched in git master within a couple of days.